# Creating A Custom Log Appender For Logging at Remote Location

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I need to create a custom log4Net appender for logging at the remote server. For that I had created a class

```
public class CustomEventLogger : AppenderSkeleton
    {
        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            string title = string.Format("{0} {1}",
                   loggingEvent.Level.DisplayName,
                   loggingEvent.LoggerName);

            string message = string.Format(
                "{0}{1}{1}{2}{1}{1}(Yes to continue, No to debug)",
                RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent),
                Environment.NewLine,
                loggingEvent.LocationInformation.FullInfo);

        }
    }
```

I had made the following changes in the **web.config** file

```
  <appender name="CustomEventLogger" type="getClientConfigurations.CustomAppender.CustomEventLogger,">
            <file value="C:\\HRNX\\log\\MultiPhraseCreateOrder\\getClientConfiguration.csv" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Date" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
            <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date{dd-MMM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss:fff},[%thread],%level,%logger,%message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I use **RemotingAppender** to log the error at remote location.
  I am very new at using the log4Net framework.

Please let me know where do I need to change.

Comment: What do you mean by "logging at the remote server", is it by fileshare, ip/socker etc.... clarify the access to the "remote server" in your question.

Comment: it is an IP/socket where we need to post the data on that endpoint. For eg, we do a post  a JSON request on a URL by a postman/RestClient

Comment: So you wanna build your own custom appender, or you want to use existing RemotingAppender? Anything wrong with RemotingAppender? I think we need clarification in here.